# can I train the Textrecognize (or the Tesseract behind) for real typewriter letters?

Tags: ocr

Can I improve result of the TextRecognize by training the machine which is behind? Id like to work with a lot of scanned texts from several (real) typewriters. It seems to me that TextRecognize gives much better results for computer fonts than for real typewriter fonts.

Comment: have an example?

Comment: You could probably train your own network, as in [143691](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143691/crack-captcha-using-deep-learning).

Comment: Anderstood - Id like using the TextRecognize features but to train the machine behind (Tesseract) to my specific data. I was not meaning creating my own neural net from scratch